# Left adjoints to several inclusions of homotopy simplicial model categories

Tags: model-categories, simplicial-stuff, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory

The left adjoint to the inclusion $sGrp\hookrightarrow sPtSet$ of the category of simplicial groups into the category of pointed simplicial sets is homotopy equivalent to the loop suspension functor $sGrp\leftarrow sPtSet:\Omega\Sigma$. This can be proved by observing that

- looping and delooping $B:sGrp \rightleftarrows sSet_0:\Omega$ is a homotopy equivalence between reduced simplicial sets and simplicial groups.
- Looping and suspension $\Sigma:sPtSet \rightleftarrows sSet_0:\Omega$ are adjoints.

The content of this is that Milnor's construction $F[X]$ of the reduced free simplicial group on a pointed simplicial set $X$ is of homotopy type $\Omega\Sigma X$.

Similarly, the left adjoint to the inclusion $sMon\hookrightarrow sPtSet$ from the category of simplicial monoids is also homotopy equivalent to $\Omega\Sigma$. The content of this is that the James construction $J(X)$ of the reduced free simplicial monoid on a pointed simplicial set $X$ is also of homotopy type $\Omega\Sigma X$.

I would like to know the left adjoints, up to homotopy, of the following inclusion functors:

1. $sGrp\hookrightarrow sGrpd$ where $sGrpd$ is the category of simplicial groupoids
2. $sMon\hookrightarrow sCat$ where $sMon$ is the category of simplicial monoids

This information would provide alternative model theoretic proofs of the corresponding algebraic constructions of simplicial objects, as with Milnor and James' constructions.

Comment: Won't this be the pointwise adjoints to inclusions of groups in groupoids (or monoids in categories)? If I'm not mistaken, the left adjoint to $Mon \to Cat$ is given by sending a category $\mathcal{C}$ to the monoid generated by morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ and modulo relations coming from composition laws in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: yeah, the algebraic constructions are easy to see. the part not obvious to me is how to find the homotopy type.

Comment: @ColinTan the homotopy they of what?